# What is $A^B$ when B has a finite cardinality?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In set theory the notation $A ^ B := \{f\mid f:B \rightarrow A \}$ right? Now a lecturer ask what was that set if $|B| < \infty$ and I think that he tried to show that the notation $\mathbb{R}^n$ is consistent with this... but I didn't know. So I need clarification on what is $A^B$ when B is finite?

Comment: I think this question is a little bit odd, because nothing happens when $B$ is finite. You can ask what the cardinality of this set is, if $A$ and $B$ are finite. But I do not know anything special about $A^B$ for a finite $B$.

Answer (score 3):

I think a better form of the question is this: What set (or better, what *construction* on sets) does $A^B$ look like when $B$ is finite?

The answer is this. Suppose $A$ is a set and $B$ is a finite set with cardinality $n.$ Then $A^B$ is in bijection with $A^n=\underbrace{A\times\cdots\times A}_{n\text{ times}}.$ This in itself isn't so interesting. What's nice is that this bijection is sort of "canonical." I'll explain what I mean by this.

Since $B$ is a finite set we may as well suppose that $B=\{1,\ldots, n\}.$ Then a function $f:B\to A$ can be thought of as an $n$-tuple $(x_1,\ldots, x_n),$ where $x_1=f(1),$ $x_2=f(2),$ and so on. We use this to define a map $\phi:A^B\to A^n,$ which is given by the rule $$\phi(f)=(f(1),\ldots, f(n)).$$ I'll leave it to you to check that it's a bijection.

The point here is that $A^B$ and $A^n$ can be thought of as "the same" when $B$ is finite, since there is a canonical way to identify these two sets with one another.

Comment: Nice answer, but I'm not sure about the "canonical" since there is no canonical way to match a set $B$ of cardinality $n$ with the interval $\{1, \ldots, n\}$.

Comment: Well I'm avoiding mentioning associativity and naturality of the product, but I think it's reasonable to say that $A^B$ and $A^n$ are in a sense canonically isomorphic.